# Why are TS errors thrown locally after checkout out a PR and not on CI?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-testing-library

I am doing some e2e testing in Cypress using TS and trying to understand why I am having TS errors locally and no errors are thrown on CI.

This is strange because I did not have the TS errors with Cypress before checking out the PR, but now I do. No tsconfig settings were changed so I am confused about why this is happening.

After checkout our this PR, I get linting over the `resolveJsonModule` option, but here is the current tsconfig I have in Cypress:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

All the TS errors that were received after cloning PR none of which were present before cloning this PR:
[image: TS errors]

**UPDATE**: Narrowed this down to a VSCODE specific issue because the app builds perfectly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the `ethers` module was added in the PR, but has not been installed in your local build. If that is the case, running `npm i` should fix it.

Comment: it ~may be a package issue but pretty sure I have everything installed already -- will install anyways

Comment: nope still get errors after doing a re-install

Comment: currently narrowing this down to a VSCODE issue

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my JSON settings in VScode to stop the errors but not sure if this is optimal:

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
```